# How to port existing iPhone application to iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal-binary

I have an iPhone application, now i want to convert that application to a universal application which runs on all the devices iPhone/iPod/iPad.
So, where to start, what things i need to do?

Any help, link, sample app, anything, will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I've done that recently, it's actually much simpler than it would seem. I recommend you read the [iPad programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) from Apple, it's about 100 pages in PDF (and you don't need to read all of it). Basically, you need to:

- run a command in Xcode that automatically converts your project to Universal
- add support for orientation changes, if you haven't done that earlier (it's required on iPad)
- go through the app, see what's broken and fix it (e.g. it's likely that you'll see some places where you need to fix autoresize settings for controls)

That's of course if you don't want to redesign the UI for iPad, which you'll probably want to do in the end (e.g. use split views, popup dialogs and various modals, and do less full screen view transitions). The UI that you'll get by going through this steps won't feel 100% iPad-y, but it will work, and will look much better than an iPhone-only app zoomed in, so it's a good start.

Comment: Thanks Psionides, actaully my application is already in submission state for iPhone/iPod. I was just wondering to make a universal app, and in this case, cant use SlipViews, etc. 

I have just read the document and upgraded my target for iPad, and it did rest of the stuff automattically, needed very few changes in other view controllers and all is done :) Thanks

Comment: You can make a universal app that has split views on the iPad, in fact, that's more or less how it should be done. You just need to make separate iPad versions of some of the NIBs and controllers and put them in a separate group/directory, and add some ifs/elses to the code. If you're careful enough, you'll get a single universal app bundle that runs on both platforms with different UIs. It just requires more work :)