# Porting my Application from iPhone to iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I know there are multiple questions about this but I wish for this one to help my specifically with my application. Here is an overview on my application:

I have a scrollview that holds a 7-page brochure. On one of the pages, there is an animation (a simple, cycling series of images). The images are currently 500x750 but the scrollview condenses them to the iPhone dimensions (to allow for zooming).

What I would like to know, is how you would see this on an iPad. I know iPads can run iPhone apps (but they are pinned to the upper corner). What considerations would I have to take into account to allow this to be displayed very well on an iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you app to display well you'll need to port it to the ipad.

You'll need to do versions of your views for the ipad screen size, or make sure that your existing views expand properly and look good on the ipad screen. I'd imagine you'd want to display your 500x750 images at their native size, and possibly add some ui furniture to fill up some of the rest of the screen space.

This question has reasonable answers for explaining how to do the port:

[How to port existing iPhone application to iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895039/how-to-port-existing-iphone-application-to-ipad)

If you don't port your app to the ipad, it will run exactly how it will on the iphone, either in a small box in the centre of the screen or magnified 2 times.